# How to change a planner's timeout?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ompl, planner, timeout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to change the planner's timeout from the default value. I've looked in the config yaml files, launch files etc, searched online, but couldn't find anything, does anyone have any ideas?
"The timeout for planning must be positive (0.000000 specified). Assuming one second instead."

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319815/how-to-change-a-planner%27s-timeout?/) by [bgd](https://answers.ros.org/users/40571/bgd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-28**:
Which planner? In which context?

**Comment by [bgd](https://answers.ros.org/users/40571/bgd/) on 2019-03-28**:
I'm using a pathplanning pipeline (it's OMPL but I haven't been able to change the specific algorithm it uses, so it defaults to RRTConnect) and making a planning_interface::MotionPlanRequest . I would like to know if it's possible to change the planning time similar to how Rviz does planning., but in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Still not quite sure what context your working in, but http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/MotionPlanRequest.html has an `allowed_planning_time` field (as well as the `planner_id` field to change the planning algorithm). You can also use the `MoveGroupInterface`, which has a [setPlanningTime](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#af4631a849c750b4c1428242475c8988d) method.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bgd](https://answers.ros.org/users/40571/bgd/) on 2019-03-28**:
Perfect! thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was after.

**Comment by [kgpton](https://answers.ros.org/users/85309/kgpton/) on 2021-10-26**:
Really i was searching for this left and right. Thnx